# npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.3:

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install npm in my project using

```
npm install
```

and I get this error

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.3:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.3:
npm ERR! sha512- 
nsyergarmMB4JCw7KGujj86ulgRYhEk8zXKRiJZdnju/irLvazQ/9Anlfsf1Rc5ypach8sZrmQDwqLGZ6AqHhnzA== integrity 
checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512- 
nsyergarmMB4JCw7KGujj86ulgRYhEk8zXKRiJZdnju/irLvazQ/9Anlfsf1Rc5ypach8sZrmQDwqLGZ6AqHhnzA== but got 
sha512-nsyergarmMB4JCw7KGujj86ulgRYhEk8zXKRiJZdnju/irLvazQ/9Anlfsf1Rc5yph8sZrmQDwqLGZ6AqHhnzA==. 
(92638 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hsr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-11T10_49_11_550Z-debug.log
```

- I tried to install latest npm globally using `--force` but I get the same error

Comment: Just remove node modules `rm -rf node_modules`, clear the cache `npm cache clean --f` and install again `npm i`.

Comment: @Arcteezy Its not working...same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove your package-lock.json and node_modules and do a fresh install:

**$ rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules**
**$ npm install**

if doesn't work Try it again, with a temporary clean cache:

**$ rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules**
**$ npm install --cache /tmp/empty-npm-cache**
If this fixes it, clear your **global npm cache** to fix the corruption.

Make sure your network connection and proxy settings 153 are ok.
Update your node and npm versions to the latest stable versions.

Comment: Thanks! The first one worked. I slightly modified the commands according to windows.