# npm install error: Integrity Check failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I have a github repo from where I pull the code and done `npm install` and that results in the error like,

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @my-package@^1.2.0:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @my-package@^1.2.0:
npm ERR! Integrity check failed:

npm ERR! Wanted: sha512-lQ...HA== 
npm ERR! Found:  sha512-nH...ow==
```

Even though I referred multiple similar solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59285967/7785337), they are mentioning that we need to delete `package-lock.json` file but my lead has asked me **not to delete** lock file and it needs to be same for all the machines.

How can I get rid of this error without deleting `package-lock.json` file?

Deleting `node_modules` and doing `npm i` doesn't do any trick
and the above mentioned error still persists..

Comment: Try deleting the node modules and npm install again

Comment: @SureshMangs, That doesn't work .. Deleting of ```package-lock.json``` file only works here but I should not do it here because in all the system we need to have exact same version..

Comment: Remove the node_modules folder and try to install the packages with "npm ci --production=false" instead of "npm install".

Comment: @ChristophDalski, After removing ```node_modules``` and running the above said command also throws the same error as like given in question..

Comment: What about cleaning the npm cache before trying to install the packages: "npm cache clean --force"

Comment: @ChristophDalski, This link works for me  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16938#issuecomment-339863980